# A word for someone who is emotionally mature?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't think of a word to describe someone who is emotionally mature

Comment: I actually pondered this very question myself, recently. The best answer I came up with at the time was: well-rounded

Comment: Why do you need to use one word?

Comment: *Mature* usually implies emotionally all by itself when used about people, given a general context. In more specific contexts, it can mean other things, like on a dating site it would mean an older person.

Comment: Tom, can you provide more context? Is there any specific aspect of "emotionally mature" you need to emphasize?

Comment: I think quite a few women I've met would argue the most obvious answer is ***female***.

Answer (score 1):

There can be various definitions of ["emotionally mature"](http://www.victoriacounsellingsolutions.com/_blog/Free_Relationship_Quiz_and_Articles/post/The_differences_between_emotional_maturity_and_immaturity/), but if I had to find common ground between them, I'd say having self-control is key.

An emotionally mature person **does not exhibit emotional volatility**, is not given to anger, is not easily offended, etc.

Therefore let me offer **"self-controlled"**:

> manifesting self-control

(Webster's Unabridged)

Sure, it's a partial match, but "emotionally mature" is a pretty broad term, so I doubt there's a single word that would encompass every aspect of it.

Answer (score 0):

The adjective 'evolved' is used in this sense, and has been for long enough to earn it a spot in the OED:

> 3. b. Of a person: spiritually or intellectually advanced. Also: modern, progressive, or **emotionally mature**.

["evolved, adj.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/65459?rskey=l8PfnD&result=1&isAdvanced=true (accessed November 06, 2015). Emphasis mine.]

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***levelheaded***.

> : having common sense and sound judgment; sensible [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/levelheaded)

.